# How to implement an ambiguous pure virtual method

Tags: c++

I would like to use `Base::push` to implement a pure virtual method `IPusher::push` in my dervied type `Derived`. But, `Derived` has its own `push` method of a different signature (yes, I need both).

```
class Base
{
public:
  void push(A);
};

class IPusher
{
public:
  virtual void push(A) = 0;
}:

class Derived : public Base, public IPusher
{
public:
  using Base::push;
  void push(B);
};
```

This fails to compile complaining that `virtual void IPusher::push(A)` is pure within `Derived`

For kicks, I tried adding `override` [mainly to see if the error was different]

`using Base::push override;`

This complained that `;` was expected before `override`

Comment: I can see that I could have `Base` implement `IPusher`, but `Base` is extremely specific, and `IPusher` in my real code as another method that makes sense for an `IPusher`, but not `Base`

Comment: So, push() in the child `Derived` class is not virtual?  You want to hide the base class definitions?

Comment: Perhaps implement `IPusher::push` as a wrapper for `Base::push`? it has to be implemented SOMEHOW.

Comment: In order to inherit in an implementation you need to use virtual inheritance from the interface. This is unrelated to the issue of introducing an overload. Perhaps try to separate these two issues in two different questions.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I don't want to hide, that's why I'm `using` it, and adding my own `push(B)` to the set. Technically, both `push(A)` and `push(B)` are pure virtuals in `IPusher`, I didn't know if that detail would just add noise to the question

Comment: ok, reading the first answer, I see my C++ KungFu is far too weak to answer you correctly.  I see something that looks and smells wrong, but the masters can tell you why.  Seems to involve live chicken sacrifices and prayers to the dark one from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would implement your questionable idea like this:

```
class Derived : public Base, public IPusher
{
public:
    void push(A a) override
    {
        // implement in terms of Base::push(A)
        Base::push(a); 
    }

    void push(B);
};
```

But don't. Re-think your design or ask some advice here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b

Comment: From what I understand `Base` is not `IPusher`; therefore, the method `push` in `Base` and `push` in `IPusher`/`Derrived` are two different things and we can't simply call the `Base::push` one like that. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Aldarrion yes, you're right, and wrong. It's an awful design, but you can call a fully qualified base class member function from a derived one.

Comment: I see now, and you're right since it's so weird and easy to miss, the design should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: After further review, a forwarding call is the only way to go. And that is because Base::push(A) is a (Base::*)(A) method, which is not convertible to the (IPusher::*)(A) at all. I can't make the compiler think they are. I need to forward to it

Comment: @payo it's very likely that the design doesn't need this complication. It might be worth explaining the motivation behind the design to someone. I'm sure a simpler solution will emerge.

Answer (score 2):

**Base code is correct**

The code you posted, apart from the obvious missing definitions of `A` and `B` is valid, but your `Derived` class remains abstract. The following compiles:

```
class A{};
class B{};

class Base
{
public:
  void push(A);
};

class IPusher
{
public:
  virtual void push(A) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base, public IPusher
{
public:
  using Base::push;
  void push(B);
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Derived remains abstract - why?**

However, the moment you try to create an object of type `Derived` - say, you add `Derived foo;` line in the main - you will get an error:

```
error: cannot declare variable ‘foo’ to be of abstract type ‘Derived’
   Derived foo;
           ^
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Derived’:
 class Derived : public Base, public IPusher
       ^
note:      virtual void IPusher::push(A)
   virtual void push(A) = 0;
```

Yes, you don't want your `IPusher::push` to be accessible directly when using `Derived`, but maybe it is reached indirectly within the bodies of other existing methods? For example, your `Derived::push(B)` might call `IPusher::push(A)`?

Or maybe someone deriving from `Derived` will try to access the `IPusher`?

You just *cannot* leave abstract methods if you want to create objects of that type - even if they are not easily accessible.

---

**Providing the definition**

So, say, you want to provide the implementation to `IPusher::push(A)` but want to hide it from your interface? In addition, you don't want it to interfere with the definition coming from `Base`.
The only solution I see to avoid the conflicting definitions is to create an intermediate class `IPusherImpl` which would provide the definition, and then inherit from it in `Derived`.
Here is a complete running example (to be compiled with c++11):

```
#include <iostream>

class A{};
class B{};

class Base
{
public:
  void push(A) { std::cout << "Base::push(A)\n"; }
};

class IPusher
{
public:
  virtual void push(A) = 0;
};

class IPusherImpl : public IPusher
{
  public:
  void push(A) override { std::cout << "IPusher::push(A) overriden in IPusherImpl\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base, public IPusherImpl
{
public:
  using Base::push;
  void push(B) { std::cout << "Derived::push(B)\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Derived foo;
  A a;
  B b;
  foo.push(a);
  foo.push(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Base::push(A)
Derived::push(B)
```

Comment: This feels like a VERY reasonable solution to my VERY weird edge case. As many have suggested, I should reconsider my larger design, which I will do. But it seems to be it is either this solution, or @RichardHodges

Comment: actually, this won't work. This brings two separate methods `push(A)`, as did my initial work. The comment by @"Cheers and hth. - Alf" was actually on point. If I want the first base type to implement a pure virtual from the second base, I need to use virtual inheritance. If you cast `foo` in your example to an `IPusher`, it calls the `IPusherImpl` method